# Power BI Rest API call limit of 120

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, powerbi-embedded, http-status-code-429, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a Power BI Report that was built using Paginated Report Visuals. Each Visual is calling Power BI API 10 times to get the report to render on the page. There are 6 of these visuals. The Report runs great the first time you open, but if you navigate or reload the page I get the 429 error, too many api calls. I found in the Microsoft Documentation that the API limit per use per minute is 120.

Is there anyway to up the limit by upgrading the license or would we need to revamp the report to not use the paginated report visuals.

Thanks,

I couldn't find anywhere in the Microsoft documentation that you get more API calls if you upgrade your license or go to premium capacity.

I did a test to remove some of the paginated report visuals and this mitigate the amount of calls to the API.

Answer (score 0):

No, as of now Power BI do not support to increase the limit amount of Rest API usages.

Power BI uses throttling to maintain optimal performance and reliability. To prevent overuse of resources from single users, Power BI limits the number of API calls within a time window per user.

For these limitations, you can take a look at the following document to know more about them:
https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/#throttling